# CakePHP : returning a non-id from a view

Tags: cakephp

I have a form in cakephp, that implements a drop down, as follows:

```
echo $this->Form->input('city', array('type' => 'select','options' => $cities,              'label' => 'City'));
```

The `$cities` array passed to the view is similar to 
`Array
(
    [0] => London
    [1] => Tokyo
)`

The form displays the names of the cities (London, Tokyo, ...).

On submission of the form, the form submits the id (key) (eg. '0' if the user selected London).   Instead, I would like to get the value (London) as text.   What changes do I need to make in the view, to return the string containing the value?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify via the `select` method:

```
    echo $this->Form->select('city', array(
        'London' => 'London',
        'New York' => 'New York',
        'Tokyo' => 'Tokyo'
    ));
```

will generate:

```
    <select name="data[Model][city]" id="ModelCity">
        <option value="London">London</option>
        <option value="New York">New York</option>
        <option value="Tokyo">Tokyo</option>
    </select>
```

See: [CakePHP manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)

Answer (score 2):

Cake fills up a select with values you provide. If You need a name of a city, you need to pass an array where your key will be this name.

```
$foo = array('London'=>'London', 'Tokyo'=>'Tokyo');
```

Answer (score 1):

Format the $cities array to an associative array, having both the 'keys' and the 'values' set to the name of the city;

```
 $cities = array(
     'London' => 'London',
     'Paris' => 'Paris',
     // etc.
 );
```

Comment: @kicaj what is the problem you're having with my answer?